# Интерфейс CharSequence

Tags: java

Имеется следующий код:

```
    public class AsciiCharSequence implements CharSequence {
    private byte[] content;

    public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
@Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int i, int i1) {
        byte[] massive = Arrays.copyOfRange(content, i, i1);

        return  new AsciiCharSequence(massive);
    }
}
```

Мне все понятно, что происходит во всех строках кода, кроме самой последней, а именно в `return  new AsciiCharSequence(massive);` Расскажите, пож-а, по-подробнее что происходит в этой строке. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этой строке создается новый объект `AsciiCharSequence` в конструктор которого передается массив байтов `massive`.

Новый объект возвращается из метода.

Данная строка эквивалентна следующему коду:

```
AsciiCharSequence result = new AsciiCharSequence(massive);
return result;
```

Вызываемый конструктор определен в этом же коде:

```
public AsciiCharSequence(byte[] content) {
```